# PHP create certificate CA not self signed

Tags: php, openssl, ca

I m trying to create a Certificate CA = not self signed. I 'm using the function PHP `openssl_x509_export`

For create Self Signed certificate no problem. But when I must create a certificate with Owner different from the Issuer I don't know how to do. I try with this code

```php
    $dn["issuer"] = array("C" => "US", "O" => "DigiCert Inc",  "OU" => "digicert.com", "CN" => "DigiCert High Assurance CA-3");
    
    $dn["owner"] = array("CN" => "twitter.com" , "O" =>"TIWTTER INC", "L" => "San Francisco" , "S"=> "California", "C" => "US" );
    
    $privkey = openssl_pkey_new();
    openssl_pkey_export_to_file($privkey, $keypath);
    $csr = openssl_csr_new($dn, $privkey);
    openssl_csr_export_to_file($csr, $requestpath);
    $sscert = openssl_csr_sign($csr, null, $privkey, 365);
    openssl_x509_export_to_file($sscert, $cerpath);
    $src = getcwd();
```

with no result

Someone know the solution?

Comment: Why not just use something like [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) to create a signed certificate from a proper CA? Is there a reason you're doing this using PHP?

Comment: yes is a tutorial  . I must create  the site with PHP and the function  openssl_x509_export_to_file . I m trying everything but for some strange reasone on the Certificate the value of Owner and Issuer is the same.. As you can see i 'm trying also with associative array but with zero result

Comment: I'm stuck on you trying to create a certificate that **isn't** self-signed. Do you have PHP error reporting turned on completely. Can you elaborate on "no result"? For instance, are none of the files being create? Most of the functions, such as `openssl_pkey_new` and `openssl_pkey_export_to_file` return `false` on failure, but I'm not seeing you check for that.

Comment: There is no error on the code what i 've write. The problem is on the file.crt where i  want  a Certificate with Subject different from issuer.= NOT self signed . I want a file.crt where i 'm the CA for example and someone ask to me the Certificate for his site.  I 've search everywhere but there is no example. If i use the normal code i obtain that subject and issuer are the same.  For this reason i 've tried also with associatve array but also in this way i don't have the aspected result. . I 've try everything.., i 've also write to php.net ma  zero result everywhere.

Comment: Fairly sure that you can't just set the issuer in the CSR, it will be set to the owner of the cert doing the signing. You need a self-signed "root" cert for your fake digicert, then use _that_ to sign the fake twitter cert.

Comment: I' m sorry but i've not understand. This is the code, how can i set php to resolve my problem?

Comment: [Root certificates (CA for this discussion) _are_ self-signed](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/168583/86698). These are "trusted" because they are installed on people's machines by the OS, browser or an admin. If you want to issue certificates that are trusted, you'll need to get your root cert installed on machines, and/or get it cross-signed by an existing CA. I would recommend ignoring PHP completely until the infrastructure is in place and you understand [how to become a CA](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/57271/86698).

Comment: Ehi man i say thank to you. But i need the instruction for setting  PHP for  create a fake Certificate CA. I know the CA, i Know the Encrrypt but i don't know the instruction PHP....this is my problem.